# Call Shell script from Automator on Catalina

Tags: command-line, automator, script, catalina

I created a Automator Program wich connect me with vpn an sets routes for split tunneling via Shell script.

The Program works fine on Mojave - now with Catalina the call

```
do shell script "sudo /Users/XXX/Desktop/routen_VPN.sh" with administrator privileges
```

produces an error

```
sh: /Users/XXX/Desktop/routen_VPN.sh: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Does it work if you run the command directly from Terminal?

Comment: Yes - works like expected in Terminal.

Comment: Note that you should not use `sudo` and `with administrator privileges` together.

Comment: No matter if I remove `sudo` or `with administrator privileges` - it won't work at all...

Answer (score 1):

Now I have a solution that works for me. If I put the content of the routen_VPN.sh in Automator in AppleScript like this
`do shell script "content of routen_VPN.sh" with administrator privileges`
it works fine.
Thanks to all who tried to help me with this! :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding the Finder to the apps having full disk access in system prefs > security & confidentiality > confidentiality tab enabled me to run a Python script (without this I was also getting an "Operation not permitted" error).

Answer (score -1):

You've created file **routen_VPN.sh** with the root user as the owner (because you used sudo), which is why you're not permitted to change the permissions as yourself.

Thus, use **sudo chmod u+x routen.sh**, but note that that will make the file only executable for the root user.

To make the file executable by everyone, use **sudo chmod a+x routen.sh**.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer but nothing changed. I've tried both - same error.

Comment: Have you grant full access for a terminal in Full Disk Access from the Privacy tab under Security & Privacy.

Comment: Yes full access is granted

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly here. Running a script with `sudo` has nothing to do with file ownership, and `sudo chmod u+x routen.sh` will make the file executable by the owner, not by root. Also, if the file is already owned by the current user, you don't need `sudo` to `chmod` it.